# Getopts behaves not as expected when option parameter is missing

Tags: bash, getopts

I have a small script that takes five positional parameters, the first two of which are optional (`-v` and `-p`) and the last three mandatory (`one`, `two`, `three`). The second optional parameter takes an argument. So far I have this:

```
#!/bin/bash

verbose=
altpath=
while getopts ":vp:" opt; do
    case $opt in
        v)  echo "-v triggered"
            verbose=true
            ;;
        p)  echo "-p triggered, param: $OPTARG" 
            altpath=$OPTARG
            ;;
        \?) echo "invalid option: -$OPTARG."
            exit 1
            ;;
        :)  echo "option -$OPTARG requires an argument."
            exit 1
            ;;    
    esac
done

shift "$((OPTIND-1))"
```

Now, if I run the script as it should be run, it behaves as expected:

```
$ myscript -v -p argname one two three
```

However, if I forget the `argname` parameter

```
$ myscript -v -p one two three
```

it does not say 'option -p requires an argument', but rather takes `one` as the argument for `-p`. Not what I want, obviously.

I understand why this happens, but I can't figure out how to solve it.

Comment: This is just an error on the part of the caller, nothing your script can or should do anything about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend to test whether there are three unprocessed arguments left once getopts has finished its work. If it is not the case, abort and print an error message.

For example, add this at the end of the script:

```
shift "$((OPTIND-1))" 
if [ ! $# -eq 3 ] ; then
    echo "Expected three mandatory arguments"
    exit 1
fi
```

Forcing an error if the argument of `-p` is omitted, is not directly supported. As a workaround, you can test whether the next argument is either missing or starts with a dash. For instance:

```
    p)  if [ -z "$OPTARG" -o "${OPTARG:0:1}" = "-" ] ; then
            echo "Error: -p requires an argument"
            exit 1
        fi
        echo "-p triggered, param: $OPTARG" 
        altpath=$OPTARG
        ;;
```

Here is the full script:

```
#!/bin/bash

verbose=
altpath=
while getopts ":vp:" opt; do
    case $opt in
        v)  echo "-v triggered"
            verbose=true
            ;;
        p)  if [ -z "$OPTARG" -o "${OPTARG:0:1}" = "-" ] ; then
                echo "Error: -p requires an argument"
                exit 1
            fi
            echo "-p triggered, param: $OPTARG" 
            altpath=$OPTARG
            ;;
        \?) echo "invalid option: -$OPTARG."
            exit 1
            ;;
        :)  echo "option -$OPTARG requires an argument."
            exit 1
            ;;    
    esac
done

shift "$((OPTIND-1))" 
if [ ! $# -eq 3 ] ; then
    echo "Expected three mandatory arguments"
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: This is a nice solution, but it doesn't work when I switch around the options: `$ myscript -p -v one two three` (I don't want their place to be fixed). Any ideas on that?

Comment: @PhilippClaßen Under standard option-parsing rules, `myscript -p -v one two three` is perfectly valid: the `-p` option was passed with the option argument "-r"; the `-r` option *was not* passed; the positional arguments are "one", "two", and "three".

Comment: Great! This works. But I have to say that I don't exactly understand the `if`-condition. If I'm not mistaken, the part before `-o` states "the number of arguments after `-p` is 0", which would be the case if `-p` were the last argument entered. Then, the second part states that the argument after `-p` starts with a dash - but I don't get how. My intuition is that it says "the character in $2 (so the argument after the current, `-p` or $1) that starts at position 0 and ends at position 1. Did I get that right?

Comment: Actually, it does not always work! These three commands behave as expected:
`$ myscript -p -v one two three`, `$ myscript -v -p one two three` (both prompting the missing argument message), and `$ myscript -p argname -v one two three` (does what it is intended to do). However, `$ myscript -v -p argname one two three)` still gives the missing argument message. I'm confused!

Comment: It indeed did! I figured out something highly similar in the meanwhile. Answer accepted :-)